# Capture class (Emgu) issue in multiple background worker threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, emgucv

I have a simple Winforms app that allows users to select multiple videos (files) simultaneously and runs background workers threads to loop through each of the videos in the BW. Have pasted code below, I get a NullReferenceException as "Unable to create capture from ..." at this line

```
Capture _capture = new Capture(videoFileName)
```

in processVideo method.

N.B: The same code work fine if I select a **single** video. So some issue with the multiple instances of Capture class.

I would expect the ProcessVideo method to have new instance of Capture and open it separately. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

```
    private void openVideoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                ofd.Filter = "Video | *.AVI;*.MPEG;*.WMV;*.MP4;*.MOV;*.MPG;*.MPEG;*.MTS;*.FLV";
                ofd.Multiselect = true;
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string[] videos = ofd.FileNames;
                    if (videos != null)
                    {

                        BackgroundWorker[] bw = new BackgroundWorker[videos.GetLength(0)];
                        int n = 0;
                        foreach (string video in videos)
                        {
                            bw[n] = new BackgroundWorker();
                            bw[n].DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
                            bw[n++].RunWorkerAsync(video);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
            }

        }


        void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = (string)e.Argument;
            ProcessVideo(filename);
        }


       private void ProcessVideo(string videoFileName)
        {

            Capture _capture = new Capture(videoFileName);
             UInt64 TOTAL_FRAMES = Convert.ToUInt64(_capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));
                for (UInt64 n = 0; n < TOTAL_FRAMES; n++)
                {
                    using (Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = _capture.QueryFrame())
                    {

//do something with the frame

                }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to update Sourcesafe service pack
it may help you

[I think you code is perfect there is
nothing wrong in it.

You got an error while creating object it clearly saw that
there may be chance that file format is not supported
or may be internal error problem.]

Let me know that after doing updation it works or not.

Regards Red

Comment: Thanks. But could not be an issue with the file format or CODEC since the same file(s) work fine when single selected. I get the error when multi-selecting.

Comment: BTW what is sourcesafe service pack? Is it the SCM tool from Microsoft? or something else? what does that have to do with this issue?